# Number of edges in a cluster of complete graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose a graph on $n$ vertices is comprised of $m$ copies of $K_r$, possibly overlapping. I wish to bound $E$, the number of edges.  Clearly, ${r \choose 2}\leq E\leq m{r \choose 2}$.  The lower bound is not that good if $n$ is large compared to $r$. Is there an easy way to improve it?

I was thinking something along the lines of partitioning $n$ vertices into $2^m$ equal sets and ignoring the interaction between them to get a lower bound of $$2^m {n2^{-m} \choose 2}.$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: Every vertex has degree at least $r-1$ so a better lower bound for $E$ is $n(r-1)/2$. And this is achieved for any disjoint union of cliques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given $n$, $m$ and $r$, so let us explore the relationship between them to see if we can't find a good lower bound. I will assume that the $m$ $k_r$ are distinct.(So, they can overlap, but not be exactly the same.) To make this problem a bit more interesting, I will also assume that for each $K_r$, there is a vertex only in that $K_r$, as to avoid redundant $K_r$'s.

Then we have 
$$
m\binom{r}2-\left\lfloor\frac{mr-n}{r-1}\right\rfloor\binom{r-1}2-\binom{r-r*}2\leq E,
$$
Where $r*=r$ if $(r-1) | (mr-n)$ and  the remainder of $\frac{mr-n}{r-1}$ otherwise.

Indeed, notice that $mr-n$ tells us how many "overlaps" happen as we place the $K_r$'s down one at a time. It isn't hard to see that the number of resulting edges is minimized when we bundle the maximum number of overlaps together(when we add a new $K_r$ that introduces only one new vertex.) This can happen $\left\lfloor\frac{mr-n}{r-1}\right\rfloor$ times and saves us $\binom{r-1}2$ edges each time. Then if there are any overlaps left over, we should do them all at once to minimize the number of edges, giving us the last term of our expression.